# DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint not getting called for first time

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating web application using
spring : 4.1.2.RELEASE
spring security version : 3.2.5.RELEASE
Front end : angular js

So when a webservice call using js is made server returns text login page as response to the call when session is expired(in my case when logged in from another system). 
So to avoid this i have added DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint bean in spring security as advised in http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/88806-use-form-login-by-default-but-http-basic-for-rest-urls
This works fine so when ajax call is made http 403 status code is sent from server.
But this happens only from second attempt.
First call made from system1 where user session is expired due to login with same user on system2.
So first web service call from system1 after session expiry returns login page html, while from next calls it return 403 error code as expected.

I am not getting why it is not returning 403 for first call .
Please help :-

Basic spring security code :-

```
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
 <beans:constructor-arg>
     <beans:map>
         <beans:entry>
            <beans:key>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher">
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="^/ws/.*" /><!-- match URLs starting with "/api/" -->
                    <beans:constructor-arg><beans:null /></beans:constructor-arg><!-- no matter what the HTTP method is -->
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:key>
            <!-- if the key above has matched, send 403 response -->
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
         </beans:entry>
     </beans:map>
 </beans:constructor-arg>

 <!-- and in the default case just redirect to login form -->
 <beans:property name="defaultEntryPoint" >
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/login.jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
 </beans:property>
```

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint">

 <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/sessionTimeout.jsp*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/sessionExpired.jsp*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/authFailed.jsp*" access="permitAll"/> -->
    <http-basic />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/index.jsp"
        login-processing-url="/loginAuth"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authFailed=true"
        username-parameter="uname"
        password-parameter="pwd"

        />
    <logout logout-url="/logoutUser" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=invalidSession" >
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.jsp?error=expiredSession"/>
    </session-management>

</http>
```

//as i am using dispatcher servlet for /ws/*.

Please advise.
Thanks